# Android P , download does not start using download manager?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to download files using the download manager and the download does not seem to be starting on Android P (running on the emulator). It works fine on Android Oreo and Android Marshmallow. Here is the code.

```
DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(URLS.URLforDownloadingFileData(fileName)));
        File file = new File(mobileInfo.getExternalFileStorageDirectory(),fileName);
        downloadRequest.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
        downloadRequest.setTitle(titleOfDownload);
        downloadRequest.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest);
```

Any idea why this could be happening and how to solve this problem? Anything to do with changes introduced in Android P?

Comment: In android O+ you can't do background download

Comment: Did you find anything useful?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493077/files-are-not-downloading-on-android-pie-9-0-xiaomi-mi-a2-using-download-mange/53845690#53845690

Comment: check this link please

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you have define [NetworkSecurityPolicy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy) for downloading urls host.
You can check it by creating of XML `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

And then reference this file in Application tag inside of your AndroidManifest.xml:

`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

If it works - it's strongly recommended to permit trafic not for all hosts, but only for needed.

Comment: not working.W/DownloadManager: [204] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Cleartext HTTP traffic to not permitted