# Download Manger not working in Android Pie 9.0 NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Tags: android, networking, download, android-download-manager, android-9.0-pie

On updating the device OS to `Android 9.0`, previously this code was working fine(*Xiaomi mi A2*). Now, files are not being downloaded on `Android Pie 9.0`.

**Moreover it is working fine in Oreo, Nougat , Marshmallow**

Here is the code snippet:

```
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp");
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                downloadUri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                        | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle("Downloading demo file").
                setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(folder_main + "/", timeStamp);

        mgr.enqueue(request);
```

**Error in logcat:**

```
11-27 11:17:28.056 4062-2814/? D/DownloadManager: [3970] Starting
11-27 11:17:28.067 4062-2814/? W/DownloadManager: [3970] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR
11-27 11:17:28.068 4062-2814/? D/DownloadManager: [3970] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
11-27 11:18:06.466 4062-2843/? D/DownloadManager: [3970] Starting
11-27 11:18:06.576 4062-2843/? W/DownloadManager: [3970] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR
11-27 11:18:06.577 4062-2843/? D/DownloadManager: [3970] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
11-27 11:19:06.581 4062-2867/? D/DownloadManager: [3968] Starting
11-27 11:19:06.737 4062-2867/? W/DownloadManager: [3968] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR
11-27 11:19:06.738 4062-2867/? D/DownloadManager: [3968] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
11-27 11:19:19.131 4062-2869/? D/DownloadManager: [3970] Starting
11-27 11:19:19.144 4062-2869/? W/DownloadManager: [3970] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR
11-27 11:19:19.144 4062-2869/? D/DownloadManager: [3970] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
11-27 11:19:36.243 4062-2872/? D/DownloadManager: [3969] Starting
11-27 11:19:36.259 4062-2872/? W/DownloadManager: [3969] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ER
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This worked for me After `Xiaomi mi A2` received software update notification today.

[image]

what worked for me

Add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` in `application` tag

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

where `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Create `xml` under `res` directory and then `network_security_config.xml` in `xml` folder like in the picture below

[image]

[This explains the issue in software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055952/downloadmanager-requests-delayed-on-android-pie)

Comment: The issue recurs after sometimes. Did you experience the same problem?

Comment: yes sometimes ...maybe issue with OS ... well which device are you testing on ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this Service class
```

---

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
public DownloadService() {
    super("Download Service");
}

String CHANNEL_ID1 = "Download Notification";
String CHANNEL_NAME1 = "Download Notification";
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private int totalFileSize;
String name;
String url;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    url = intent.getStringExtra("url");

    createChannels();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri sounduri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID1);
    builder.setContentTitle("Download");
    builder.setContentText("Downloading File");
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setLargeIcon(bm);
    builder.setSound(null);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());


    initDownload();

}

private void initDownload() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("Your Url") //Url Base here
            .build();

    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadFile(url);// pass your Url
    try {

        downloadFile(request.execute().body());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Folder name";
    File folder = new File(path);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    int count;
    byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
    long fileSize = body.contentLength();
    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
    File outputFile = new File(path, name + ".mp3");// file name & extension
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    long total = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int timeCount = 1;
    while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {

        total += count;
        totalFileSize = (int) (fileSize / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));
        double current = Math.round(total / (Math.pow(1024, 2)));

        int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / fileSize);

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        Download download = new Download();
        download.setTotalFileSize(totalFileSize);

        if (currentTime > 1000 * timeCount) {

            download.setCurrentFileSize((int) current);
            download.setProgress(progress);
            sendNotification(download);
            timeCount++;
        }

        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    onDownloadComplete();
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    bis.close();

}

private void sendNotification(Download download) {
    builder.setProgress(100, download.getProgress(), false);
    builder.setContentText("Downloading file " + download.getCurrentFileSize() + "/" + totalFileSize + " MB");
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}


private void onDownloadComplete() {

    Download download = new Download();
    download.setProgress(100);
    notificationManager.cancel(0);
    builder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
    builder.setContentText("File Downloaded");
    //builder.setVibrate(null);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    notificationManager.cancel(0);
}

public void createChannels() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel notifiCationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID1, CHANNEL_NAME1, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notifiCationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notifiCationChannel.enableVibration(false);
        notifiCationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        notifiCationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        notifiCationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        notifiCationChannel.setSound(null,null);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notifiCationChannel);

    }
}
}
```

---

Call this method from Your activity/fragment and pass url and name

```
private fun startDownload() {
    val intent = Intent(this, DownloadService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("name", name)
    intent.putExtra("url", url)
    startService(intent)

}
```

---

```
Retrofit Interface 

interface RetrofitInterface {

@GET
@Streaming
fun downloadFile(@Url url: String): Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code, But i am looking to use download manager class