# Download failed with error 400 when using Android Pie

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-9.0-pie

I've been using DownloadManager in a production app without problems but now it fails in Android Pie (API 28). Please note that the download is marked as failed and returns error 400.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    query.setFilterById(reference);
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int statusIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    int status = cursor.getInt(statusIndex);

    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
        int fileUriIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI);
        String savedFileUri = cursor.getString(fileUriIndex);

        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = null;
        try {
            pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.parse(savedFileUri), "r");
            PamplonaParkingXMLParser pamplonaParkingXMLParser = new PamplonaParkingXMLParser();
            ParkingList parkingList = pamplonaParkingXMLParser.parse(pfd);
            ObservableObject.getInstance().updateValue(parkingList);
            if (pfd != null) {
                pfd.close();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getDetail().getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    } else if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED){
        Log.e(TAG, "Download failed");
        int reasonIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
        int reason = cursor.getInt(reasonIndex);
        Log.e(TAG, reason +"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try these solutions

> **Solution 1**)

Add this line in application tag in `manifest` file

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

like below

```
<application
            android:name=".ApplicationClass"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Add this tag in application tag in `manifest` file

> **Solution 2**)

Add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` in application tag

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

where `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

[image]

Create `xml` under res directory and then `network_security_config.xml` in `xml` folder
For more info refer my answer
[Download Manger not working in Android Pie 9.0 (Xiaomi mi A2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493077/files-are-not-downloading-on-android-pie-9-0-xiaomi-mi-a2-using-download-mange)

Comment: Thank you, I was using <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"> and so on trying to explicitly allow only clear text traffic to a domain, but didn't work. Your solution finally solved the issue.

Comment: i am glag it worked , please accept my answer to others so others can use it

Comment: Setting cleartextTraffic permission for all domains by default is not very secure way how to solve this. I wander, if there is a possibility to discover what exactly causes error 400. In my case, I know the particular URL and domain, however <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"> simply don't work :(

Comment: try the solution 2 and let me know