# Problem with connecting my android app to php in android 9

Tags: php, android, mysql, wampserver

I need some help with my android app.
My app uses a php file to connect to MySQL database and do some CRUD operations. It was working fine on all mobile phones but suddenely it stoped working on some phones. After searching for the problem reasons I noticed that all phones not working updated to android 9 and I tested my app on new phones with android 9 and the same problem found.

My app is connecting to php file and MySQL database on wampserver on my lap.

I have updated android studio build tools to android 9.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: link contains https:// ?

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54720414/6880611)

Comment: You need to give us more info. Have you done any debugging? When you say "stopped working", what actually happens? Errors? Start by doing some proper debugging (check for errors, check if the request reaches the server and so on) and update your question to include that info together with the relevant code.

Comment: Check if your link is implementing http:// or https://. Android security for clear text traffic is updated from Android 9

Comment: please add more details like Magnus has suggested. See also [mcve] – what you describe is impossible to reproduce since you gave us almost no details and literaly no code